# How to fix host-port issue on kubernetes dashboard setup on linux?

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, amazon-linux, kubernetes-dashboard

In the Amazon Linux machine while trying to install a Kubernetes dashboard there was an error which is been unpredictable.

This is a new Amazon Linux server in AWS,there was an error while installing the Kubernetes dashboard regarding host and port issue, but  so nothing has configured in it as a new server. And I've installed kubectl and awscli for checking but it doesn't work. I've tried on all community support but there is no issue placed like mine.

while running the command

```
$ kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
```

It throws the error

```
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Comment: Are you tried to install like this? `kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0-beta4/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml`
[installetion guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/)

Comment: Yeah i've tried it, again the same error is thrown

Comment: ```
unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0-beta4/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml": Get http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
```

Comment: Do you experience this problem only when creating new resource ? What about other operations that make calls against the api-server like `kubectl get nodes` or `kubectl get pods` ?

Comment: Are you sure that you `kubectl` works?

Answer (score 0):

[setup kubectl correctly](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/)

add admin.conf (your cluster config) in your `KUBECONFIG`

Example:

```
export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/.kube/admin.conf
```